# eclipse autocompletion from class file?

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete

when i use netbeans and includes a class in a phpfile and then type $class_name-> it will show all functions and properties of that class.

how can i do that with eclipse?

Comment: Added php to your tags since most people will assume you're talking about java with those tags and that title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should work, but I would recommend a recent eclipse and PDT.

At the beginning of PDT, there used to be some completion issues like [bug 167626](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=167626), but they are fixed by now.
Do indicate to eclipse what Php you are using (4? 5? see [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.pdt/msg03227.html)), and make sure your project is opened as a Php one (see [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.php/msg00737.html))

Answer (score 0):

Code completion in PDT works when Eclipse can understand what is the target class. In some cases this can be derived from the code (e.g. when you have a variable which is assigned an instantiation of a class). In other cases, it is derived from PHPDoc comments which denote the type of vars and arguments, method return types, etc.

See [this article](http://code.neox.net/2009/03/10/eclipse-pdt-code-completion-and-zend-framework/) for example.

In any event using $class_name-> makes no sense. You need to use a variable name and, in case the variable is recognized as a type, you will get the complete list of methods/field.